# C# TabPages added at runtime don't autosize the parent form

Tags: c#, runtime, autosize, tabpage

I have a simple form that contains a TabControl where the TabPages are added at runtime. I have gotten all of this to work *almost* as I want it to, however when I set the form to autosize, it ignores the runtime TabPages in the calculation... How can I either force the form to delay the autosizing until the TabPages have been added, or force the form to recalculate when a new TabPage is added?

**EDIT**: For the record, I'm testing this out by starting my app at 640x480 (using the MinimumSize property) and including a control that is 750 wide.

Comment: What happens if you turn autosizing off and then back on after adding the tab?

Answer (score 0):

Would using the `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` do the trick? Here's the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) that explains how it works.

You call `SuspendLayout()` first, add the tab pages, then `ResumeLayout()`.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

What about using TabPage.Dock = DockStyle.Fill?

Comment: TabPages don't have a Dock property. It's up to the TabControl to Dock, which it already does.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're no longer having this problem, but this might be helpful for anyone else searching for a solution. You can set the MinimumSize of the TabControl to be the MinimumSize of the largest TabPage that you add. TabPages don't have a MinimumSize of their own, so you'd have to have a single fully Docked control in the TabPage on which you could check the MinimumSize.

I already had this setup (using a FlowLayoutPanel to lay out the contents of the TabPage) so it was relatively simple, not sure if it would be so easy for others. I know it's a really unpleasant 'solution' to the problem, but I couldn't find another way of forcing the TabControl to update itself properly.